# Write 1s faster to col-rows based on positions in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to pandas. I'm using a dataframe to tally how many times two positions match.

Here is the code in question...right at the start. The "what am I trying to accomplish" below...

```
def crossovers(df, index):
    # Duplicate the dataframe passed in
    _dfcopy = df.copy(deep=True)
    # Set all values to 0
    _dfcopy[:] = 0.0
    # change the value of any col/row where there's a shared SNP
    for i in index: 
        for j in index:
            if i == j: continue # Don't include self as a shared SNP
            _dfcopy[i][j] = 1
    # Return the DataFrame. 
    # Should only contain 0s (no shared SNP) or 1s ( a shared SNP)
return _dfcopy
```

**QUESTION:*** 
The data is flipping all the 0s in a dataframe to 1s, for all the intersections of rows/columns in  a list (see details below).

I.e. if the list is

```
_indices = [0,2,3]
```

...all the locations at (0,2); (0,3); (2,0); (2,3); (3,0); and (3,2) get flipped to 1s.

Currently I do this by iterating through the list recursively onto itself. But this is painfully slow...and I'm passing in 16 million lines of data (16 mil indices).

***How can I speed up this overall process?***

***LONGER DESCRIPTION***

I start with a dataframe called `sharedby_BOTH` similar to below, except much larger (70 cols x 70 rows)- I'm using it to tally occurrences of shared data intersections.

Rows (index) are labeled 0,1,2,3 & 4...70 - as are the columns. Each location contains a 0.

***sharedby_BOTH***

```
    0   1   2   3   4 (more)
   ------------------
0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
(more)
```

Then I have a list, which contains intersecting data.

```
_indices = [0,2,3 (more)] # for example
```

This means that 0, 2, & 3 all contain shared data. So, I pass it to `crossovers` which returns a dataframe with a "1" at the intersection places, obtaining this...

```
    0   1   2   3   4 (more)
   ------------------
0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0
1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0
3 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0
4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
(more)
```

...where the shared data locations are (0,2),(0,3),(2,0),(2,3),(3,0),(3,2).

***Notice that self is not recognized [(0,0), (2,2), and (3,3) DO NOT have 1s] ***

Then I add this to the original dataframe with this code (inside a loop)...

```
sharedby_BOTH = sharedby_BOTH.add(crossovers(sharedby_BOTH, _indices)
```

I repeat this in a loop...

```
for pos, pos_val in chrom_val.items(): # pos_val is a dict
    _indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(pos_val["sharedby"]) if (x == "HET")]
    sharedby_BOTH = sharedby_BOTH.add(crossovers(sharedby_BOTH, _indices))
```

The end result is that `sharedby_BOTH` will look like the following, if I added the three example `_indices`

```
sharedby_BOTH = sharedby_BOTH.add(crossovers(sharedby_BOTH, [0,2,3] ))
sharedby_BOTH = sharedby_BOTH.add(crossovers(sharedby_BOTH, [0,2,4] ))
sharedby_BOTH = sharedby_BOTH.add(crossovers(sharedby_BOTH, [0,2,3] ))

    0   1   2   3   4 (more)
   ------------------
0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 2 | 1
1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
2 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1
3 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0
4 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0
(more)
```

...where, amongst the three indices passed in...

`0`shared data with `2` a total of three times so (0,2) and (2,0) totaled three.

`0`shared data with `3` twice so (0,3) and (3,0) total two.

`0`shared data with `4` only once, so (0,4) and (4,0) total one.

I hope this makes sense :)

***EDIT***

I did try the following...

```
addit = pd.DataFrame(1, index=_indices, columns=_indices)
sharedby_BOTH = sharedby_BOTH.add(addit)
```

BUT...then any locations within `sharedby_BOTH` that DID NOT HAVE SHARED DATA ended up as `NAN`

I.e...

```
sharedby_BOTH = pd.DataFrame(0, index=[x for x in range(4)], columns=[x for x in range(4)])
_indices = [0,2,3 (more)] # for example
addit = pd.DataFrame(1, index=_indices, columns=_indices)
sharedby_BOTH = sharedby_BOTH.add(addit)

     0     1     2     3     4 (more)
   ------------------
0 | NAN | NAN |  1  |  1  | NAN
1 | NAN | NAN | NAN | NAN | NAN
2 |  1  | NAN | NAN |  1  | NAN
3 |  1  | NAN |  1  | NAN | NAN
4 | NAN | NAN | NAN | NAN | NAN
(more)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd organize it with numpy slice assignment and the handy `np.triu_indices` function.  It returns the row and column indices of the upper triangle.  I make sure to pass `k=1` to ensure I skip the diagonal.  When I slice assign, I make sure to use both `i, j` and `j, i` to get upper and lower
triangles.

```
def xover(n, idx):
    idx = np.asarray(idx)
    a = np.zeros((n, n))
    i_, j_ = np.triu_indices(len(idx), 1)
    i = idx[i_]
    j = idx[j_]
    a[i, j] = 1
    a[j, i] = 1
    return a

pd.DataFrame(xover(len(df), [0, 2, 3]), df.index, df.columns)

     0    1    2    3
0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
3  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
```

**Timings**

```
%timeit pd.DataFrame(xover(len(df), [0, 2, 3]), df.index, df.columns)  
10000 loops, best of 3: 192 µs per loop

%%timeit
for i,j in product(li,repeat=2):
    if i != j:
        ndf.loc[i,j] = 1
100 loops, best of 3: 6.8 ms per loop
```

Comment: Its crazy fast. So much faster than mine, I cant even make it a percentage. For 10000 iterations, it took 4 secs. My code, at 10000 iterations...well, I didn't have the patience to wait ;D Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use itertools product and loc for assignment i.e

```
from itertools import product
li = [ 0,2,3]
ndf = df.copy()
for i,j in product(li,repeat=2):
    if i != j:
        ndf.loc[i,j] = 1

   0  1  2  3  4
0  0  0  1  1  0
1  0  0  0  0  0
2  1  0  0  1  0
3  1  0  1  0  0
4  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: The code is cleaner, but unfortunately the time us about the same.

Comment: @RightmireM Pir's solution would be the fastest of all the approaches to come.